# jQuery $.get() Order Doesn't Match

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, get

The php returns my arrays ordered by name, but when I use $.(get), they're ordered by id.

```
{
"34":{"id":"34","name":"Amber","assigned":1},
"72":{"id":"72","name":"Bob","assigned":0},
"7":{"id":"7","name":"Charlie","assigned":0},
"3":{"id":"3","name":"Gary","assigned":1}
}

$.get("/assign", { clasa: clasaDL.attr('id') },
  function(data){
    var checked, boxes = "";
    $.each(data, function(n, val) {
      checked = (val.assigned == 1) ? 'checked="yes"' : '';
      boxes += '<input type="checkbox" ' + checked + ' value="' + val.id + '" />' + val.name;
    });

  $('#dialog').html('<form id="assign">' + boxes + '</form>');
}, "json");
```

Question is: How can I order it by name, and not by id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript objects are not ordered. While most browser keep the initial order, e.g. Chrome doesn't.

If you want sorted data, use an array - if you need access using a key which is not suitable for an array (non-numeric or lots of unused keys between the actual element keys), create an object containing key => array index mappings.

So your JSON could look like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {"id":"34","name":"Amber","assigned":1},
        {"id":"72","name":"Bob","assigned":0},
        {"id":"7","name":"Charlie","assigned":0},
        {"id":"3","name":"Gary","assigned":1}
    ],
    "mappings": {"34": 0, "72": 1, "7": 2, "3": 3}
}
```

Then you could iterate over `data` or access an element by its id using `data[mappings['yourid']]`

Comment: So my return is an object, and not an array?

Comment: Yes, as soon as you have named keys/curly braces, you have objects. Arrays are lists which have indexes from 0..n-1